# How to estimate angles from acceleration and acceleration from angles in 3 dimensions?

Tags: java, math, trigonometry, accelerometer, kalman-filter

I saw several questions about this in lots of forums, but none of them resulted me clear enough or precise enough for my needs. Or I just didn't understand them, that's another possibility.

Well, consider several accelerometer measures (3 dimensions) (m/s^2) taken by a device (that's not an android device, and no real time processing is needed here). I'm reading these values from a text file and need to convert them to degrees.

The first code I tried was :

```
   private static final double G = 9.81;
   private static final double RAD_TO_DEG = 180.0 / Math.PI;
    
   private double[] calculateAngles(double acX, double acY, double acZ) {
        
       double accelX = acX * G;
       double accelY = acY * G;
       double accelZ = acZ * G;

       double angleX = Math.atan2(accelX, Math.sqrt(accelY * accelY + accelZ * accelZ)) * RAD_TO_DEG;
       double angleY = Math.atan2(accelY, Math.sqrt(accelX * accelX + accelZ * accelZ)) * RAD_TO_DEG;
       double angleZ = Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(accelX * accelX + accelY * accelY), accelZ) * RAD_TO_DEG;
        
       return new double[] { angleX, angleY, angleZ };
   }
```

This code "seems" to give me a good result. At least, credible. I put my accelerometer in a fixed position, noticed the 3 angles (***UPDATE***: I'm talking about yaw, pitch and roll) given by a random measure, turned the accelerometer by 90º (approx) and one of the angles added this more or less 90º to its value.

Nevertheless, the inverse operation I tried doesn't work at all :

```
private static final double RAD_TO_DEG = 180.0 / Math.PI;
private static double[] calculateAccelerations(double angleX, double angleY, double angleZ) {

        // Convertir les angles en radians
        double radianAngleX = angleX * DEG_TO_RAD;
        double radianAngleY = angleY * DEG_TO_RAD;
        double radianAngleZ = angleZ * DEG_TO_RAD;

        double accelX = Math.tan(radianAngleX) / Math.sqrt(1.0 + Math.tan(radianAngleX) * Math.tan(radianAngleX) + Math.tan(radianAngleY) * Math.tan(radianAngleY));
        double accelY = Math.tan(radianAngleY) / Math.sqrt(1.0 + Math.tan(radianAngleX) * Math.tan(radianAngleX) + Math.tan(radianAngleY) * Math.tan(radianAngleY));
        double accelZ = Math.tan(radianAngleZ) * Math.sqrt(1.0 + Math.tan(radianAngleX) * Math.tan(radianAngleX) + Math.tan(radianAngleY) * Math.tan(radianAngleY));

        return new double[]{accelX/G, accelY/G, accelZ/G};
    }
```

If I take my initial accelerometer values, estimate yaw, pitch and roll, convert them to accelerations... how to say... Inventing the values would be more accurate. The first question is... why? I can't see my mistake here.

Googling for alternatives, Kalman filter has been the most relevant result I could find to do this. I found an implementation in common-math3 (Apache), but I can't understand how this is working nor if it really applies here.

What I need would be read those accelerometer values and estimate what would have been those values with the accelerometer positioned in a different way. To do that, I need to be able to "estimate" what are the accelerometer position, add the angles I need to add to virtually change its orientation, and go back to accelerometer values.

Ideally a Java suggestion, but any help, including agnostic explanation, is welcome!

Comment: I don't understand what angleX-Z mean. You start with what are presumably cartesian accelerations acX-Z yes? Are you trying to calculate accelerations in spherical polar coordinates?

Comment: Hi, sorry if it's not clear. I think the exact names of these angles/values in English are yaw, roll and pitch. What I need is deduce what are yaw, roll and pitch from a 3 dimensional acceleration, and its contrary. Deduce a "possible" acceleration from given yaw, roll and pitch data. Acceleration expressed in m/s^2 and yaw, pitch and roll in degrees.

Comment: An object has 6 degrees of freedom in 3D space, 3 for position and 3 for orientation. Acceleration in m/s^2 pertains to position. Are you sure you're trying to do something that makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, what do you want your angles to measure? From the calculation that you have in `calculateAngles`, what you seem to be calculating is this:

angleX

the angle between the "x" accelerometer measure and the floor. (that is, when the "x" measure is pointing straight up you get 90°, when the "x" measure is pointed at the horizon you get 0° and when the "x" measure is pointed at the floor you get -90°)

angleY

the angle between the "y" accelerometer measure and the floor. (that is, when the "y" measure is pointing straight up you get 90°, etc, same as with "x")

angleZ

the angle between the "z" accelerometer measure and straight up. (that is, when the "z" measure is pointing straight up you get 0°, when the "z" measure is pointed at the horizon you get 90° and when the "z" measure is pointed at the floor you get 180°)

Given your followup comment, I'm going to assume that these are actually the angles you wish to measure and continue from there.

Now, because of the function you're using in that method (`atan2`), multiplying all three acceleration measures by the same constant has no effect; therefore, the `* G;` step can be omitted in `calculateAngles`.

So first, I'd change that function to just:

```
   private double[] calculateAngles(double acX, double acY, double acZ) {
       double angleX = Math.atan2(acX, Math.sqrt(acY * acY + acZ * acZ)) * RAD_TO_DEG;
       double angleY = Math.atan2(acY, Math.sqrt(acX * acX + acZ * acZ)) * RAD_TO_DEG;
       double angleZ = Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(acX * acX + acY * acY), acZ) * RAD_TO_DEG;
        
       return new double[] { angleX, angleY, angleZ };
   }
```

Now, to reverse the calculation, we're going to need to use the fact that when we're done we should have that the sum of the three accelerations squared should equal `G` squared. Also, we'll want to use the fact that to reverse

```
 angle = Math.atan2(y, x);
```

You generally shouldn't use the `tan` function, but should instead use:

```
 x = Math.cos(angle);
 y = Math.sin(angle);

 // then multiple x and y by some scaling factor
```

So:

```
private static double[] calculateAccelerations(double angleX, double angleY, double angleZ) {

    // Convertir les angles en radians
    double radianAngleX = angleX * DEG_TO_RAD;
    double radianAngleY = angleY * DEG_TO_RAD;
    double radianAngleZ = angleZ * DEG_TO_RAD;

    double acX = Math.sin(radianAngleX);
    double acY = Math.sin(radianAngleY);
    double acZ = Math.cos(radianAngleZ);

    // use this if you need the sum of the acceleration squared to be G squared
    //double scaling = G / Math.sqrt(acX*acX + acY*acY + acZ*acZ);
    // EDIT Cheloute: with scaling = 1, that works perfectly for my use case
    double scaling = 1;

    return new double[]{acX*scaling, acY*scaling, acZ*scaling};
}
```

Note though that although the `calculateAccelerations` function will spit back values for any three input angles, that doesn't mean that any three angle combinations are actually valid; for example, the way you've got your measurements set up, `angleY` is restricted to being between `-abs(abs(angleX)-90)` and `abs(abs(angleX)-90)`, and given `angleX` and `angleY`, I'm pretty sure it's possible to determine `angleZ` or at least narrow it down to only two possibilities.

However, if you feed `calculateAccelerations` angles that came out of `calculateAngles` you should get back the original accelerations, or close enough.

Comment: Hi, thanks! To try to clarify what I'm doing... In reality, I don't care about any absolute "angle" values. I have 2 different devices with 2 different accelerometers positioned in a different way. If I put the device to get a correct result What I need to do is "transform" the data emitted by the second one as if it were positioned like the first one. if we compare the 2 accelerometers to slices of bread with butter, the first one is positioned on a table, butter upside, while the second one will be on the thin longer side on the left of the 1st slice, butter looking at the first slice.

Comment: Ah, so you mean that you have three accelerometer readings from a thing in position 2 and wish to transform them into three accelerometer readings from something in position 1, because you have software that expects "dev 1"-type readings, but in a new version of project you only have something in position 2. Something like that?

Comment: That’s the case, yes. Legacy app i want to [try to] use with a newer device, but i need to adapt these data first. Next gyro data, but that’s another story… first execution of your code didn’t give me the expected result, but that may be due to the scaling factor.. i need to make some other tries

Comment: OMG! If I change "scaling" by 1 instead of "G / Math.sqrt(acX*acX + acY*acY + acZ*acZ);" I get the exact same values!! Thank you so muuuuch !!! If you agree I edit your answer to validate it, replacing the current value of scaling by 1